# How to convert raster byte array of an image to original image in java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, raster

I need to convert bytes of an image to original image. My byte array which is created by  WritableRaster.And Itried to convert to  original form ,but it produced image without original colors.My tries are below

```
try {
        BufferedImage readImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg"));
        byte imageData[] = get_byte_data(readImage); // Then I need to convert this to original image

        DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(imageData, imageData.length);
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, 3 * width, 3, new int[]{0, 1, 2}, (Point) null);
        ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorModel.getRGBdefault().getColorSpace(), false, true, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, true, null);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("image.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static byte[] get_byte_data(BufferedImage image) {
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    return buffer.getData();
}
```

Comment: What did you do to convert the Raster back to "original" image? A BufferedImage comprises of a Raster and a ColorModel. The ColorModel knows how to interpret the image data.

Comment: I deals with colormodel in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong with your code:

change this line:

`WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, 3 * width, 3, new int[]{0, 1, 2}, (Point) null);`

to

`WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, 3 * width, 3, new int[]{2, 1, 0}, (Point) null);`

will work because the original image data is in BGR format instead of RGB.