# How can a create an image out of an array of RANDOM bytes

Tags: java, image-processing

I've been working with the google quickdraw data set but I've been having some trouble processing the data. I'm working in java, I've downloaded the data and converted each file into byte arrays (e.g. full_numpy_bitmap_anvil.npy becomes a byte array of 98965104 bytes, roughly 126231 pictures). I want to be able to recreate these pictures from the byte array. The trouble I've been having is this; I can split the array into the relevant subarrays (of 784 bytes each) but I can't turn them back into pictures, as you can't write random bytes to an image in the usual way
e.g.

```
 ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
 BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis);
 ImageIO.write(bImage2, "jpg", new File("output.jpg"))
```

without getting the error message

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
```

I need some way of writing individual pixels to a new Buffered Image maybe? Or is there some other way to do this?

NOTE: I'm aware this sort of processing would be easier in python but as I said I'm working in java.

Comment: *"**roughly** 126231 pictures"* --- Roughly? So you don't know exactly how many?

Comment: I'm going by the length of the array divided by 784 (each image is 28 by 28) that was meant to just be an example.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `ImageIO.read(InputStream input)` method, passing in a `ByteArrayInputStream` created using the [`ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] buf, int offset, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream-byte:A-int-int-) constructor for one of those 784-byte chunks, e.g. `ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray, 0, 784))` for the first image?

Comment: Same exception unfortunately

Comment: Then the file is not a concatenation of 126231 pictures of 784-bytes each. Why do you think it is? Check your assumptions.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using the numpy bitmaps what are 28 x 28 grey scale images, no additional data apart from the first 80 bits of the file which is header data

Comment: So you are *now* saying that the 784 bytes is actually 28x28 bytes of greyscale pixels, and super important piece of information that is entirely missing from the question? I.e. the bytes are not in any graphics file format known to `ImageIO`, so it's no wonder it cannot create an image from the data. Perhaps you should **edit** and ***clarify** the question, explaining exactly what the bytes are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting a bufferedImage from a bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809558/getting-a-bufferedimage-from-a-bytearray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need some way of writing individual pixels to a new Buffered Image maybe?

If that is what you need, sure you can do that. Here's an example that creates a 100x100 gray scale image with random pixels:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
byte[] data = buffer.getData();

Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = (byte) rng.nextInt(256);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what I need a nested loop if I wanted to draw the picture accurately? So, for example the first 28 bytes are the first row of pixels, next 28 are the second row of pixels etc. (basically plotting x and y coords)?

Comment: No need for nested loop, the data is laid out linearly. First 28 bytes in the array would be the first row, the next 28 would be the second row. Assuming you created the image with width 28. Or do you mean you want ONE big image that is a collage of your small images?

Comment: I was going to try with one first, the collage was the next step!

Comment: If you start with a byte array it's more efficient to construct the `BufferedImage` around it instead of copying data to the empty array of a new `BufferedImage`. Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34809906/1052284 The `DataBufferByte` constructor can use an offset so you just pass the same array to all your images with different offsets. Also see this for a possible pitfall: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28283623/1052284